# Glassfish LDAP logging is filling up log files

Tags: logging, glassfish, ldap, glassfish-3, java.util.logging

We are running Glassfish 3.1.2.2 integrated to an Active Directory server via LDAP.  The LDAP authentication works just fine, but we continually see the logs filling up with messages like this:

```
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:48.765+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.release(): notify; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.311+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LdapPoolManager: using authmech: simple|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.311+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@11e21097 {x.x.x.x:389:::null:glassfish=com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.ConnectionsRef@44f43371}.get(): x.x.x.x:389:::null:glassfish|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.311+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@11e21097 {x.x.x.x:389:::null:glassfish=com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.ConnectionsRef@44f43371}.size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.311+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool@11e21097 {x.x.x.x:389:::null:glassfish=com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.ConnectionsRef@44f43371}.get(): size after: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.311+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.get(): before; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.327+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ConnectionDesc.tryUse() com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168 idle|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.327+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.get(): use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.327+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.327+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.get(): after; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.342+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.release(): com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.342+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections@7e60743d.release(): release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168; size: 1|#]
[#|2014-02-21T20:45:49.342+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Release com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient@5ec0d168|#]
```

This is just a sample; logging like this repeats endlessly, to the point where the vast majority of our log files consist of these statements.  The odd thing is that these are logged at the SEVERE level, and yet the messages look informational to me.  None of them sound like true errors.

My first thought was to configure javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging to only log at the fatal level.  This did get rid of the log messages above, but unfortunately it turns off all sorts of other useful logging within Glassfish as well, so it isn't really an option.

Any ideas what the log messages above mean, and how to turn them off?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like logging of the LDAP Connection Pooling. I don't know how exactly you've implemented the LDAP integration but per default this logging is not enabled, you have to set it as an JVM property.

```
com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug
```

This can be set to `fine` or `all`, unfortunately there is no explicit option to turn it off other than removing this property.

You can set it either with:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug", "all");
```

or as additional JVM option in the GlassFish admin GUI with

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=all
```

**Maybe this is set up somewhere in your code or in your GlassFish instance.**

If this doesn't help you may try to set the log level for `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool` to `OFF`.

**See also:**

- [LDAP Connection Pooling Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html)

Comment: I took a look at our server, and sure enough we do have that property set with a value of "all".  Although I have not had a chance to test yet, based on the documentation this certainly sounds like the issue.  Thanks.